# How to setup iphone usb ethernet tethering with iOS 14.x and Ubuntu 20.10 on Rasberry Pi 4

Tags: networking, usb, raspberrypi, 20.10, iphone

I recently installed `Ubuntu Desktop 20.10` running kernel `5.8.0-1015-raspi` on my Rasberry `Pi 4` and facing issues to troubleshoot why usb ethernet tethering is not working with my Iphone running `iOS 14.1`.

From scratch when I plug in my iPhone with USB on the Pi, Ubuntu is automatically detecting the connection as `Apple Ethernet Connected` with correct Default Route / DNS route being my Iphone as well iOS displaying me that I share my connection but all requests to 0.0.0.0 seems to go no where.

I then installed both `ipheth-utils` and `libimobiledevice` as apparently needed but still facing same issues.

I ran `traceroute` while being connected on usb tethering with my iPhone (with and without `ipheth-utils` `libimobiledevice`) where ICMP ping is successful to 172.20.10.1 but traceroute gave me nothing :

```
~$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
```

I ran `traceroute` while being connected on wireless with my iPhone :

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (172.20.10.1)  3.497 ms  3.387 ms  3.217 ms
 2  172.24.79.202 (172.24.79.202)  51.614 ms  51.432 ms  51.251 ms
 3  172.24.67.229 (172.24.67.229)  50.873 ms  50.896 ms  49.183 ms
 4  172.24.226.221 (172.24.226.221)  49.025 ms  48.839 ms  48.662 ms
 5  172.24.226.222 (172.24.226.222)  48.130 ms  48.298 ms  27.517 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
```

Does `Ubuntu Desktop 20.10` is intend to work from scratch in tethering mode with iPhone on latest iOS ?

Any suggestions how I can solve or troubleshoot that further ?

EDIT Here with some further details :

```
~$ apt list --installed | grep "ipheth-utils\|mobiledevice"
    
ipheth-utils/groovy,now 1.0+git20111206-0ubuntu5 arm64 [installed]
libimobiledevice-utils/groovy,now 1.3.0-5 arm64 [installed]
libimobiledevice6/groovy,now 1.3.0-5 arm64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: Don't know simple solution for it. Anyway... https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/1038

Comment: Probably you need kernel 5.10 or higher.

Comment: I do believe the same indeed. 
Looks like mainline package is not available for arm64 yet so I will have to manually move from 5.8.0 to 5.10.